# How can I use integer that I supply into tf.placeholder(tf.int32)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I need to initialize a dynamic list which has length given by an integer that I will put into a placeholder through feed_dict.

I set up the graph through this code:

```
num_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32) 
input_data = list() 
for _ in range(num_placeholder):
    input_data.append(1)
```

But get the following error: `'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

How can I use the `int` that I put into the `num_placeholder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num_placeholder` is a `Tensor` object, it can not be directly used as an `int`, it must be valuated first. See documentation on [`placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder) method.

If you want to use `num_placeholder` object as `int` you must evaluate it as follows:

```
# create a placeholder       
num_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

# create an identity operation
# because same Tensor can not be both fed and fetched
num_op = tf.identity(num_placeholder)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # feed value to placeholder and fetch it
    num = sess.run([num_op], feed_dict={num_placeholder: 5})
```

Now `num` will is a list `[5]` and you can use `num[0]` in your loop. I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but if your goal is to create a vector of ones of some custom length that is fed during runtime, here is how it can be solved by means of Tensorflow:

```
num_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
ones_op = tf.ones(shape=[num_placeholder], dtype=tf.int32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ones = sess.run([ones_op], feed_dict={num_placeholder: 5})
```

`ones ==> <type 'list'>: [array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)]`,
see [`ones`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#ones)

Comment: I'm doing language modeling so I'm putting in a sentence of varying length for each training step. So I'm trying to put each word as a one hot encoded vector into the input list. What you showed above works, but is there any way I can put each word into a list? I'm trying to initialize the list to have n placeholders (1 for each word in the sentence). But the placeholder for the length of the list doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: Sure, you can have placeholders of variable length, just provide `None` as first dimension, this will allow to have a batch of variable length. For example `input_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 10])` creates a placeholder that can hold an arbitrary number of entries, where each entry has `10` features. Then it is up to you how do you encode words.

Comment: Can I access individual entries in `input_data`? If I want to get the first entry in `input_data` will `input_data[0]` work? I thought a placeholder is a Variable and you can't access indvidual entries?

Comment: Yes, you can access individual entries, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146444/tensorflow-python-accessing-individual-elements-in-a-tensor). Another question is why you want to access individual entries inside Tensorflow session, usually there is no need for that. I think that this comment thread has gone beyond the initial question, so I would suggest you to ask a new question regarding implementation details of your particular problem.