# Extracting a sub-tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, tensor

I have a 2 x 4 `tensorA = [[0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0]]`.
I want to extract index i from dimension d.
In Torch I can do: `tensorA:select(d,i)`.

For example, `tensorA:select(0,0)` would return `[0,1,0,1]` and 
`tensorA:select(1,1)` would return `[1,0]`.

How can I do this in TensorFlow? 
Easiest way I could find is: `tf.gather(tensorA, indices=[i], axis=d)`

But using gather for this seems like overkill. Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: How about `tensorA[d,i]`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35158370/1586200) answer work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow python : Accessing individual elements in a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146444/tensorflow-python-accessing-individual-elements-in-a-tensor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following recipe :

replace all axis but d by semicolon, and put the value i on axis d, eg :

```
tensorA[0, :]  # same as tensorA:select(0,0)
tensorA[:, 1]  # same as tensorA:select(1,1)
tensorA[:, 0]  # same as tensorA:select(1,0)
```

However, when I tried this, I had a SyntaxError :

```
i = 1
selection = [:,i]  # this raises SyntaxError
tensorA[selection]
```

So I used a slice instead, as in

```
i = 1
selection = [slice(0,2,1), i]
tensorA[selection]  # same as tensorA:select(1,i)
```

This function does the trick :

```
def select(t, axis, index):
    shape = K.int_shape(t)
    selection = [slice(shape[a]) if a != axis else index for a in 
                 range(len(shape))]
    return t[selection]
```

eg :

```
import numpy as np
t = K.constant(np.arange(60).reshape(2,5,6))
sub_tensor = select(t, 1, 1)
print(K.eval(sub_tensor)
```

prints

> [[6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.],
>
> [36., 37., 38., 39., 40., 41.]]

Comment: Instinctively, I first tried ``tensorA[*selection]`` to unpack the list selection. Yet unpacking didn't work (SyntaxError: invalid syntax). Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `value = tensorA[d,i]`. Under the hood, tensorflow calls
[`tf.strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice)

Comment: I don't think this would work. Wouldn't it return the element in row d and column i? If so, this isn't what I am looking for.