# Python access datatype object

Tags: python, object, numpy-ndarray

This might be a stupid question. I have a class "di" which contains an attribute "train_indices". If I access that, I get the following result:

```
di.train_indices
# array({'bike': 0, 'car': 1, 'motorcycle': 2, 'other': 3, 'truck': 4, 'van': 5}, dtype=object)
```

How do I access those values? I would like to do something like that:

```
di.train_indices[0]
bike
```

But this is not working. Any help is very welcome.

Comment: What is `type` of `di.train_indices`?

Comment: I get it like that:
```from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 
train_set = train_generator.flow_from_directory(...)
train_indices = train_set.class_indices```

Comment: It is a dict which is in an array

Comment: give the array example ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow python : Accessing individual elements in a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146444/tensorflow-python-accessing-individual-elements-in-a-tensor)

Comment: @elsmu you just need https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html#numpy.ndenumerate

Answer (score 0):

Its Very simple

```
# lets define your class as below
class d1:
     import numpy as np
     train_indices = np.array({'bike': 0, 'car': 100, 'motorcycle': 2, 'other': 3, 'truck': 4, 'van': 5}, dtype=object)


# now lets declare and call it
x1 = d1()


# lets iterate through array now 
for index, value in np.ndenumerate(x1.train_indices):
    print(index, type(value),value['car'])


# output:
() <class 'dict'> 100
```

One more Example :

```
import numpy as np
train_indices = np.array({'bike': 0, 'car': 100, 'motorcycle': 2, 'other': 3, 'truck': 4, 'van': 5}, dtype=object)

for index, row in np.ndenumerate(train_indices):
    print (index,row)
    for x,y in row.items():
       print(x ," : ",y)

**output:** 
() {'bike': 0, 'car': 100, 'motorcycle': 2, 'other': 3, 'truck': 4, 'van': 5}
bike  :  0
car  :  100
motorcycle  :  2
other  :  3
truck  :  4
van  :  5
```

For Ref : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html#numpy.ndenumerate